# Trigonometry Integration Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

For example,

If I integrate $$\int \frac{3\sec^2x}{3\tan x+6}dx$$

I'll get $$\ln (3\tan x+6)+c$$

Okay, now I integrate $$\int \frac{\sec^2x}{\tan x+2}dx$$

I'll get $$\ln(\tan x+2)+c$$

Obviously they have a different answers.

Next If I integrate $$\int \frac{3 \cos x}{3\sin x+6}dx$$

I'll get $$\ln (\sin x+2)+c$$

If I integrate $$\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x +2}$$

I'll get $$\ln (\sin x+2)+c$$

Why the first example has a similar answer whereas the second example has a different answers?

Comment: Your error is red.

Comment: Edited. Thanks! @Salahamam_Fatima

Comment: $\ln(3\tan x + 6) +c_1 = \ln(3(\tan x +2)) +c_1 = \ln3 + \ln(\tan x+2) + c_1 = \ln(\tan x +2) + c_2$

Answer (score 3):

$\require{cancel}$

In the first case, with your result: $\ln (3\tan x+6)+c$,

note that $$\begin{align} \ln (3\tan x+6)+c &= \ln\big((3(\tan x + 2)\big) + c \tag{factor out $3$} \\ \\ &= \ln 3 + \ln(\tan x + 2) +c\tag{$\ln (ab) = \ln a+\ln b$}\\ \\  &= \ln(\tan x + 2)+ C\end{align}$$

Note that $\ln(3)$ is a constant.  So essentially, we can absorb $\ln(3) + c =C$.

The point is that the integrals are the same, up to a constant.

Also note that both integrals have, in fact, the same integrand: $$\int \frac{3\sec^2x}{3\tan x+6}dx = \int\frac{\cancel 3\sec^2 x }{\cancel 3( \tan(x)+2)} \,dx= \int \frac{\sec^2 x}{\tan x +2}\,dx$$

The best approach here is to first simplify the integrand, and then integrate.

---

In the integral $$\int \frac{3 \cos x}{3\sin x+6}dx$$  If you had first done as you did in the earlier integral, you would have:

$(3\sin(x) + 6)' = 3 \cos (x)$, with the integral yielding $$\begin{align}\int \frac{3\cos x}{3\sin x + 2} &= \int \frac{3\sin (x) + 6)'}{3\sin(x) +6} \\ \\ &= \ln(3\sin x+6) + c \\ \\ &= \ln\big(3(\sin x + 2)\big) + c\\ \\ &= \ln 3 + \ln(\sin x + 2) + c \\ \\ &= \ln(\sin x + 2) + C \end{align} $$  Again, this could have easily been integrated by first simplifying the integrand, which you seem to have done.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\ln(3\tan x+6)+C&=\ln(3(\tan x+2))+C\\
&=\ln3+\ln(\tan x+2)+C\\
&=\ln(\tan x+2)+C\end{align}$$
In short, the $3$ was absorbed by the constant and both functions are the same with the difference of an arbitrary constant, as all antiderivatives are.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(3\tan x +6)+c=\ln3+\ln(\tan x +2) +c=\ln(\tan x+2) + c_1$

You get the "same" answer(upto a constant) in both cases as $\ln 3$ just gets absorbed in the constant.

The same will happen in the second example.